# Firebase query does not return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I coded a function for sending a query to my database and retrieve the result. But if it does not find anything in the database it returns nothing neither `undefined` nor `null`.

For this reason, I can not handle whether the data exists in the database or not.

What is the return value of this function?

---

**Code:**

```
usersRef
  .where("nickname", "==", nickname)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>
      doc.data() ? console.log("a") : console.log("b")
    );// i wrote this line for testing the issue
    querySnapshot.size == 0 ? (flag = true) : (flag = false);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("err2"))
```

If the data exists in the database, it prints `a`, but if not, it prints nothing, neither `a` nor `b`.

I used that code in my React-Native project, it also uses a Firebase Firestore database and `usersRef` means:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const usersRef = db.collection("Users");
```

---

**Note:** the `querySnapshot` always return a firebase object in JSON format. The `doc` parameters in `forEach` returns an object if it exists in JSON format but, if not, it cannot be handled.

**Note 2:** I also tried `doc.data()== null` or `doc.data()== undefined` or `doc.data()== ""`. But they do not print anything in `console.log()`. I also tried `console.log(doc.data())` and nothing changed.

Comment: Does `console.log(doc.data())` not log anything?

Comment: If the data exists in my database it returns the data otherwise it does not log.@Daniel_Knights

Comment: Are you logging *outside* the `forEach`? Only reason I can see for nothing happening is `querySnapshot` has a length of `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the data exists in database, it prints a but if it does not exist it prints nothing neither a nor b

That's because you're querying the database and getting back an array. If your array has 1 or more items in it, your `.forEach` call will iterate through them and execute your ternary expression, resulting in a console log call - either `a` or `b`. *However, if your array is empty,* then `.forEach` won't have anything to iterate over, and so the function you're passing to it will never be executed.

```js
[].forEach(item => console.log(item)) // nothing
[1].forEach(item => console.log(item)) // 1
```

So the issue is that your database query is just coming back empty on your Windows box. Check your `flag` variable or the `.size` member and you should see whether this is the case:

```js
usersRef
  .where("nickname", "==", nickname)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>
      doc.data() ? console.log("a") : console.log("b")
    );
    querySnapshot.size == 0 ? (flag = true) : (flag = false);
    console.log(querySnapshot.size);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("err2"))
```